# Pointer not inheriting base class methods

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I just started learning polymorphism and am stuck with smth. I have a base class `Object`, and a derived class `Ball`. I would like to achieve polymorphism and use `Ball` methods on an `Object` pointer as such:

```
Object *ball = new Ball(P, dPdt, s, Forces);

cout << ball->getP() << " position\n" << ball->getdPdt() << " speed\n";
```

The first one,  `getP()`, works fine because it's a method of the `Object` class and `Ball`'s constructor calls `Object`'s constructor to initialize it. Now, when it comes to `getdPdt()`, the compiles complains that *no member named `getdPdt` in `Object`*, which is obvious since I defined it in `Ball`. What am i doing/understanding wrong here ?

**PS:** I need by `*ball` to be an `Object` since this is for a physics simulation and everything must be an `Object` in order to simulate it. Later on, I guess I'll add a `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` to keep track of

Comment: Nothing is wrong here, `Object*` only provides `Object` methods, that is desired. If you need Ball functionality, you need to use `Ball*`, casting to `Object*` loses information on what kind of object it stores.

Comment: You can either define `getdPdt` as a virtual function in `Object`, or downcast the pointer `ball` to be `Ball*` and call `getdPdt` on it (which may be a bad idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language. If the *static* type of an expression is `Object`, then it can do whatever an `Object` can do (and nothing else). If it's a `Ball`, then it can do whatever a `Ball` can do. You want it to be an `Object` but be able to do what `Ball` can do. You cannot have both, you need to decide one way or another.

Polymorphism is not about making properties that are exclusively defined for `Ball` magically available through an `Object` pointer. It is about `Ball` properties inherited from `Object` behave in  a `Ball`-specific way.

Note that

```
Object *ball = new Ball(P, dPdt, s, Forces);
dynamic_cast<Ball*>(ball)->getdPdt();
```

can only be read this way:

```
 Object *ball = new Ball(P, dPdt, s, Forces); 
// I want to create a Ball but forget that it's a Ball
// I want to only remember that it's an Object

dynamic_cast<Ball*>(ball)->getdPdt();
// No! It's really a Ball after all! 
// My decision to forget it was wrong! I regret it!
```

Now anyone looking at these two lines of code would wonder whether you really know what you want, and rightfully so. Don't do things that you regret at the next line.

The situation is more complicated if these two lines are not next to each other. For example, you may have a vector of `Object*`:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back(new Ball(whatever));

// in a totally different function in a totally different file
dynamic_cast<Ball*>(objects[i])->getdPdt();
```

Now the questions that the astute reader would be asking are different, but no less difficult. Why is it known that `objects[i]` points to a `Ball`? Why isn't this knowledge encoded in the type of the variable? That's what types are for in C++. Recall that C++ is a statically typed language. Any exception to this (and `dynamic_cast` is naturally an exception, what with it having the word "dynamic" in it) should be extremely well justified. If there is some code that decides what to do based on the type of the variable, that code should generally be a method in the base class.

In the end there are only two different things you can do while staying in the object-oriented design paradigm. Either add `getdPdt` to `Object`, so that it is available for all `Object`s; or put your `Ball`s in a separate basket whose type says that there are `Ball`s inside, and not just `Object`s. `dynamic_cast` is a deviation from the OO paradigm. Whether a deviation is acceptable to you is up to you to decide, but if you find yourself deviating from it a lot, then perhaps you want to consider a different paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

If `Object` is a polymorphic type, a quick and dirty solution is to downcast.

```cpp
Object *ball = new Ball(P, dPdt, s, Forces);
dynamic_cast<Ball*>(ball)->getdPdt();
```

This works only if you're sure that `ball` points to an `Ball` object. Otherwise, checks must be done before calling `getdPdt` on the casted pointer.

---

Note that the above solution goes against the goal of *polymorphism* that you wanted to achieve. Polymorphism is about providing a single interface (in this case the `Object` class) to entities of different types (in this case all of the subclasses of `Object`, including `Ball`). The interface should be designed such that all required operations are accessible through `Object*`.

Better polymorphic solution if defining `getdPdt` for `Object` makes sense:

```cpp
class Object {
public:
  virtual int getdPdt() const {
    return 0;
  }
};

class Ball : public Object {
public:
  int getdPdt() const override {
    return 42;
  }
};

int main() {
  Object* obj = new Ball();
  // this returns 42, despite obj being `Object*`
  obj->getdPdt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't that be the same as `Ball *ball = new Ball(...)` ?

Comment: Not quite the same thing. With downcast, you can store the `Ball*`s as `Object*`s somewhere, while still using the methods specific to the `Ball` type when you're sure that the pointer is actually pointing to a `Ball`.

Note that *the need to access methods of the subtype may be a sign of bad design* of your system. Consider defining virtual functions in the base class instead.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more info that did not fit well in the comments.

Comment: You also need to always check the result of `dynamic_cast<Ball*>`. If the object wasn't really a `Ball` then the cast returns a nullptr.